# Should Callen's derivation about energy minimun principle care about the case that the extremum condition can't be achieve?

Tags: thermodynamics

Callen's Postulate II says

> The values assumed by the extensive parameters in the absence of an internal constraint are those that maximize the  entropy over the manifold of constrained equilibrium states

Then Callen use it to derive energy minimum principle , especially ,he used the condition that ${\partial _X}S = 0$.But when the entropy is maximized, the ${\partial _X}S $may not be zero, because the maximum value can be taken at the boundary.  If the problem has boundaries, then even a smooth function can have a maximum at the boundary, and its derivative will not be equal to zero at the maximum point. Does this situation needs to be taken into account?

Answer (score 0):

The abstractness of the presentation might be getting to you. Remember to try seeing what is happening with some actual examples. Here, $S=S(E,V,N)$, say. While there is a minimum amount of $E,V,N$ to consider, there is actually no maximum for those. The boundary that you are worried about is thus infinitely far away. Your worry is thus not going to happen.

Another reason to consider that this is actually impossible, is that we are always thinking about the thermodynamic limit. That is, the system is being modelled by an infinitely large system of the same $T,p,\mu$, that we chop out a chunk of the correct $E,V,N$ to consider, in so doing, throwing away the corrections from having boundaries, in favour of treating the bulk as being more important. When you think of it this way, again, the boundaries are then not actually there.

We are thus safe to take the simpler considerations.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder if you would like to see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/789104/why-is-sum-limits-j-v-j-mu-j-0-sometimes-cant-be-achieved  There ,the boundaries actually need to be taken into account. So I actually was worried about that problem . So if the Gibbs Potential Minimum Principle's derivation somehow loses its validity(since dG isn't zero),need I reconsider the validity of the derivation of the energy minimum principle?

Comment: Yes, I think you would have to do that. The answers there are explicitly saying that you have to do that, too.

Answer (score -1):

Callen assumes an isolated system in which there are several partitions. Within each partition there is a homogeneous matter in some phase whose state is given by its internal energy $E$, volume $V$, and chemical components $n_k$, along with its temperature $T$, internal pressure $p$, and chemical potential $\mu_k$. The partitions are rigid, impermeable and adiabatic, therefore any kind of energy exchange between the homogeneous parts, such as, volume change, diffusion, and heat conduction are excluded, and equilibrium is maintained by these walls (partitions).

Each part has its own *equilibrium* entropy, and the total entropy is the sum of those partial entropies. The intensive parameters may differ across the partitions, say some neighbors may have different pressures but the wall between them is rigid, not moving, and either side stays unaffected by that pressure difference.

Now remove any number of partitions and wait until a *new* equilibrium is achieved. If there were pressure or chemical potential or temperature differences separated by the walls that got removed now those differences would get equalized. If not all the walls got removed, then within the isolated system some intensive parameters may still vary across the walls, but within those parts whose internal walls got removed the new equilibrium demands the homogeneity of these intensives.

According to *Postulate II*, in the new equilibrium, the total entropy of the system cannot be smaller than in the old equilibrium.

What Callen does not say here is that the only time when the entropy of the new equilibrium is the same as that of the old is when we remove walls on whose either side intensive parameters happen to be the same. If even one wall is removed with at least one pair of different intensives, the new entropy will be *larger* than the old.

Irreversible equilibration generates entropy, and spontaneous equilibration that starts in disequilibrium is irreversible. This is the essence of Postulate II.

It is also implicitly assumed that the entropy is a positive smooth bounded function of its variables for any finite phase, and thus it has a maximum. You may have phase changes but that also comes with a different entropy *function*, again smooth and bounded.